# Unable to login to graphical interface after changing password on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: login, password, 15.10

I'm currently using Ubuntu 15.10 and recently changed my password and it works okay, but after rebooting my system I can't login anymore using the graphical interface. When I enter from the command line interface, I can login normally. I make sure that the problem wasn't the password change during Ubuntu installation in a virtual machine and tried the same thing again, I realize that when I use the * character in my password this error occurs. Any suggestions on why?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, login and change the password:

```
passwd
```

Then, please make a bug report:

```
ubuntu-bug lightdm
```

Descripe your problem there, so they can fix it.

Comment: So did it help? Can you set this as solution?